# SharePoint SLK and T-SQL xp_cmdshell safety

Tags: sharepoint, t-sql

I am looking into a TSQL command called "xp_cmdshell" to use to monitor a change to a the SLK (SharePoint Learning Kit) database and then execute a batch or PowerShell script that will trigger some events that I need.  (It is bad practice to modify SharePoint's database directly, so I will be using its API)

I have been reading on various blogs and MSDN that there are some security concerns with this approach.  The sites suggest that you limit security so the command can be executed by only a specific user role.

What other tips/suggestions would you recommend with using "xp_cmdshell"?

Or should I go about this another way and create a script or console application that constantly checks if a change has been made?

I am running Server 2008 with SQL 2008.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but it sounds like you're going to be using a trigger on various events that will use xp_cmdshell to call some other process - how will you do this without modifying the database? I didn't know you could call arbitrary TSQL from the SharePoint API?

Comment: I would create a stored procedure that runs when something is changed in the SLK Database.  The SLK database is separate from the SharePoint database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a CLR SP using C# and have that take care of your calls to the API and any other external processes from within it.  That would be much safer and easier to manage because then you only need to grant execute access to the CLR SP.

Comment: I am actually going to write a console application that just monitors the sql table.  Thank you for the suggestion